# Backbone event propagation clarification

Tags: backbone.js

With the below code we are able to prevent `handler1` from firing when clicking the second button.

```
var See = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click': 'handler1',
    'click .c2': 'handler2'
  },
  handler1: () => console.log('First handler'),
  handler2: (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Second handler');
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<button>One</button><button class="c2">Two</button>');
    return this;
  }
});
```

How can this be? What path does the propagation take? Any insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors... It won't run. Please make sure the code you post can demonstrate the problem before you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-165), the events registered via view's event's hash are delegated to the respective view's `el`, except events which do not specify a selector which is registered directly on the view's `el`.

> What path does the propagation take?

The propagation always takes the normal path - from the child to it's parents.

In this case the event bubbles from the button to the view element, when it reaches the view element the delegated click handler for the button is fired first <sup>1</sup> which prevents further propagation <sup>2</sup>, So the direct handler on the view element is not invoked.

---

<sup>1</sup> According to [order-of-event-handling-in-jquery](https://www.box.com/blog/order-of-event-handling-in-jquery/)

> In jQuery, delegates are privileged event handlers and are allowed to jump the queue. In fact, they are always stored in the front of the queue. This mechanism allows delegates to fire before direct events.

<sup>2</sup> jQuery probably (*because I didn't bother to check the source code to confirm, that's the way it should be*) checks whether `e.stopPropagation()` have been called before invoking each handler to mimic normal bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

propagation will flow from child to parent element if propagation is not stopped.

Answer (score 0):

The First event you are listening to, is basically any click made inside the view area and is caught when it propagates to the view's root element.

The second event is caught whenever a click is propagated to the .c2 element, all DOM events propagate from the source element up to the parent.
If you stop the propagation in .c2, then the click will never reach the parent.

```
events: {
  'click': 'handler1', // This catch clicks propagated to the view root 
  'click .c2': 'handler2 // this catch clicks in propagated to .c2 elem
},
```

Comment: *"The second event is caught whenever a click is propagated to the .c2 element"* -  this is not true.